relacion de tablas PHPMYADMIN
Alguien me puede ayudas a resolver mi problema?, tendo dos tablas, tarimas y detalle_tarimas. quiero hacer una relacion entre las dos tablas por fecha y cliente, sin embargo al relacionarlas me conbina informacion que no corresponde al cliente. ya utlice, INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGTH JOIN, CROSS JOIN, pero no logro hacer la consulta correcta.
Esta es la primer ocnsulta que hice, mientra solo habia un cliente todo bien, pero al ir agregado mas clientes la consulta ya no fue la adecuada.
SELECT tarimas.fecha,tarimas.saldo_inicial ,detalle_tarimas.ingreso,detalle_tarimas.salida,tarimas.saldo_final FROM tarimas LEFT JOIN detalle_tarimas ON tarimas.fecha=detalle_tarimas.fecha_movimiento WHERE tarimas.cliente='GAFATY' AND tarimas.fecha>='2024-07-01' AND tarimas.fecha<='2024-07-31'
Tabla tarima:

Tabla detalle_tarimas:

Resultado de la consulta:

al parecer esta convinando las salidas e ingresos de otros clientes.

Está mezclando cosas de diferentes clientes porque no estás usando el id del cliente en tu join... estás usando una fecha. Cualquier combinación que tenga la misma fecha, sea del cliente que sea, se utilizará en el producto cartesiano uses left, right o inner o lo que quieras. No he visto nunca usar una fecha para un join... las fechas no son únicas y no identifican a nadie en concreto :/ Si quieres que no "mezcle" tienes que usar el id de cada cliente para identificarlos.

Por cierto, PHPMyAdmin nada tiene que ver con tu pregunta: es una herramienta para manipular bases de datos, pero no es un SGBD/DBMS :) Tu pregunta se refiere exclusivamente a MySQL (¿o MariaDB?) Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, dándole formato a tu consulta SQL.

ya modifique lo de PHPMyAdmin, gracias por la observacion.

A tu consulta le falta relacionar las tablas por la columna cliente de ambas tablas en tu clausula JOIN. También te sugiero utilizar la expresión BETWEEN para realizar una consulta de un rango de fechas poniendo como primer parámetro la fecha inicial y como segundo parámetro la fecha final que deseas consultar (BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-07-31').
Además te recomiendo usar un alias para tus tablas, de esta manera evitas escribir el nombre de la tabla completa para llamar sus campos. En este caso la tabla tarimas la identificare con el alias t y la tabla detalle tarimas la identificare con el alias d, asi por ejemplo para llamar el campo fecha de la tabla tarimas lo hare de la siguiente manera: t.fecha
Podrías intentar de la siguiente manera:
SELECT t.fecha,t.saldo_inicial ,d.ingreso,d.salida,t.saldo_final 
FROM tarimas t 
LEFT JOIN detalle_tarimas d 
ON t.cliente = d.cliente AND t.fecha=d.fecha_movimiento 
WHERE t.cliente='GAFATY' 
AND t.fecha BETWEEN '2024-07-01' AND '2024-07-31'


Por favor escribe tus respuestas así que explicas como tu código resuelve el problema. En este caso es algo como "Las tablas están relacionadas por cliente y fecha, pero en tu join las relacionas solamente con fecha y así produces una mexcla de clientes. Tienes que poner el cliente en la cláusula ON también."

De acuerdo, lo haré en próximas ocasiones. Gracias por la observación.

En siguientes ocasiones??? Y por qué no en esta?? Usa el enlace [edit] debajo de tu respuesta y añade la información restante!

Por favor, lee [answer] y pulsa en [edit] para agregar más detalles a tu respuesta. No dejes para mañana lo que puedes hacer hoy ;)

Listo, ya detalle un poco mas mis respuesta, espero ser claro, gracias por su observaciones. En próximas respuestas tratare de ir mejorando mi redacción, espero me comprendan soy nuevo en la comunidad.

Tu respuesta me servio al 100, muchas gracias, tomo en cuenta todas tus recomendaciones.

en lugar de utilizar LEFT JOIN utiliza INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN siempre obtendrá los datos de la primera tabla.

Lo cual seguirá siendo problemático porque hay diferentes clientes que han hecho compras en la misma fecha, ergo saldrán unidos en el left join también.

Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas en el centro de ayuda.
